# Using this this in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with this in Jquery. When I do that on my website, it returns me the window.width. I just want to access the element from within. This is an example.

```
<div class="section " style="width:400px"></div>

$( ".section" ).html($(this).width());
```

or

```
<div class="section "><p></p></div>

$( ".section p" ).html($(this).parent().width());
```

also here is JSFiddle  [jsfiddle.net/XY66w/1](http://jsfiddle.net/XY66w/1)

Comment: working fine in fiddle. you forgot to add jquery lib. http://jsfiddle.net/XY66w/1/

Comment: Would be great if you can clarify a little bit what you're trying to do - I'm not sure I understand the question completely.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mp7g5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that when you attempt to write this code:

```
<div class="section " style="width:400px"></div>

$( ".section" ).html($(this).width());
```

What you're trying to do is show `400px` inside the `div.section`. If that is what you're trying to do, then here's what's happening:

This statement:

```
$( ".section" ).html($(this).width());
```

if Javascript, or most other languages I know, is syntactically equivalent to this:

```
var newHTML = $(this).width();
$( ".section" ).html(newHTML);
```

As you can see, this isn't a jQuery issue - but more a JavaSciprt / any programming language problem. You're telling the browser to pass in a value to the `.html()` method, so it must calculate that value first, **in the scope of the function that you're calling the method *from***. In this case, you're calling the method from the `window` or global scope (or some other undefined scope, so you will never get what you expect.

The simple fix is this:

```
var section = $('.section');
section.html(section.width());
```

On the other hand, there are some jQuery methods that *accept functions* and these are the ones that you seem to be thinking of in this case. For instance, things would be slightly different in case you were using the `each` method, which accepts a function:

```
$('.section').each(function(index, element){
    $(this).html($(this).width());
});
```

In this case, you're passing in a function that jQuery will then call in the scope of each element that is matched by your selector.

The big difference is to differentiate when you're passing in a value and when you're passing in a function that will be evaluated later.

Comment: You assumed correctly and really clarified everything. Also is this a good alternative ? http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mp7g5/1/

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but I think the `html` method works on only the first element - which means that it will work for the first `.section` but not for others if you have more than one. Just check that up.

Comment: No, scratch that. `html` works on all matched elements. So that should work fine.

Comment: To be exact, it works on all matched elements when it's being used to _set_ the HTML (i.e. when it's given an argument), it uses the first matched element when it's used to _get_ the HTML (when given no argument).

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want this way, I think:

```
$(".section").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).width());
});
```

JavaScript, like a lot of common languages, is not a "lazy" language. An expression statement like yours is evaluated such that all the function parameters are determined before anything's actually called. By using the jQuery `.each()` API, you can act on each element of the selected set.

Comment: The OP wants the window width, not section.

Comment: @epascarello well maybe; it's really hard to tell. Why does the OP want to put the width into the visible content of an element?

Comment: @epascarello I'm not positive but because of the second example the OP posted (going after the parent) it does appear the OP is going after the section width…  Ambiguous for sure :)

Comment: It was an example, I want to access the element that is all. Also why do I have to use Each? isn't $(".section") the same? doesn't find all elements and does an action.

Comment: @CrisG it's not entirely clear what you want `this` to be. JavaScript has really clear rules about `this`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery only binds `this` when it's calling a function, such as an event handler, a callback function, a function supplied to something like `$.each`, etc.

In your examples, you're just supplying an argument to a jQuery method, and it's not inside a function that was called by jQuery. So `this` just contains whatever the browser's context is, which is `window` for top-level code. It's *not* the element(s) matched by the selector `.section`.